# linear functions/hyperplanes vs. convex functions/convex sets in Hilbert space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, convexity

The [simplest Hahn-Banach extension theorem in Hilbert space $X$ avoids the use of the axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531814/the-hahn-banach-theorem-for-hilbert-spaces-follows-from-rieszs-theorem?rq=1) by virtue of the Riesz representation theorem. But what about the version of the theorem where the sought-for linear functional is required to remain below a given sub-linear or convex function? Also, to which extent can we separate 2 disjoint convex sets by a hyperplane without Zorn? Can we assert that any hyperplane $H\subset X$ has a translate that is tangent (*) to a given bounded closed convex subset $C\subset X$?

This question has an [identical counterpart on stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122556/hyperplanes-and-convex-sets-in-hilbert-space).

(*) "tangent" means that the linear bounded function whose kernel represents the hyperplane is non-negative on $C$ but not strictly positive.

Comment: To separate a point $x$ from a closed convex set $C$, one can take the best approximation $y\in C$ to $x$ and a hyperplane perpendicular to $x-y$.

Comment: And similarly one can find nearest points between closed convex set and a disjoint compact convex body, but that's about "the best" that I'm aware of.